# div with 3 rows and scrollable content at the middle

Tags: html, css

I have to do 3 rows div with scrollable content at the middle row.
Container is absolute position and can't be larger than 100% of the document height.
Container height depends of rows height, and middle row has dynamic height from x to x px.

Can't use max-height: x vh, bacuse of older browser incompatibility.

```css
/* main container can't be larger than 100% of the screen */
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  background: green;
  max-height: 100%;
}

/* this needs to be scrollable if dynamic content is to large */
.middle-row {
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: blue;
}  

/* this always needs to be visible */
.last-row {
  
}  

.dummy-large-div {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-row">some thing</div>
  <div class="middle-row">
    <div class="dummy-large-div"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="last-row">
    <button>submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned that you need to support Android 4x - that makes flexbox a viable option ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox))

The code also becomes very simple.

Just add the following to the container class

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

and the following to the middle row:

```
 .middle-row {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex:1;
}
```

Also, be sure to add -webkit- prefixes to support Android 4.1-4.3

### [FIDDLE 1 (little content)](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/c7fz3r0x/4/)

### [FIDDLE 2 (lots of content)](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/0d0eo79h/1/)

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background: green;
  max-height: 100%;
}
/* this needs to be scrollable if dynamic content is to large */

.middle-row {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-row">some thing</div>
  <div class="middle-row">
    <div class="dummy-large-div">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
      took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
      sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="last-row">
    <button>submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow that looks promising, just checking if it works with older browsers

Comment: I based this answer on your comment that you need support for android 4x browsers - take a look at the caniuse link for browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a height to the .container class. It is auto by default and the content is a relative height.

Comment: I can't specify height of the container because its dynamic and depends of rows height. I just want container to not be larger than 100%, and 3 rows always visible. Middle row has dynamic height.

Comment: Now this is a better question. There are essentially three ways to do this depending on how much browser support you want. You can use css [calc()](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) to calculate sizes for mixed relative and fixed sized heights. It is not supported by older browsers. Alternatively you can use a border-box trick for a solution that is supported by older browsers. If you target newer browsers you might also take a look at flexbox.

Comment: It needs to be supported by all android 4x stock browser. This is abit sad, otherwise i could use vh

Comment: Well it works almost ok. There is a problem on IE11, I can't see the content.